# I want to erase registered BLE devices directly from the app

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubxoi.jpg)

I want to delete the registered device from the app like the above captured picture.

Can I erase a registered BLE device with a 'swift' code?

Comment: No, unpairing is not possible within app code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i also face same problem but According to some research i found that Currently, the only way to unpair a Bluetooth accessory is by the user to manually "forget" it in Bluetooth Settings.

but yes, you can disconnect your BLE with below code

```
centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(yourPeripheral)
```

reference from:-   https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/4732

i hope it will be help full for you :)